# Decimal fields are not working properly after publishing in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some decimal fields to show and edit in my view in a table.

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Score, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" } })</td>**
```

They work all great before I publish it on my server. However when I publish the project on the server there is a /00 character at the end of each field and user have to delete them before submit the form.
What should I do?

[image: I apologize that the form is in Persian format.]

Answer (score 0):

I should add

```
    <globalization culture="en-us" uiCulture="en-us" />
```

to Web.config in `<system.web>`